# looping strings without for loop or counter in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc, char

My objective is to loop through a predefined set of strings while printing each one on its own line without the use of a counter variable. The lines I have commented out is the working code, but requires a counter. The four lines below it have stumped me.

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    char *astring[500];
    astring[0]=(char*)"ABC";
    astring[1]=(char*)"DEF";
    astring[2]=(char*)"GHI";
    astring[3]=(char*)NULL;
    //long count;
    //for (count=0;count<4;count++){
    //printf("%s\n",astring[count]);
    //}
    char *p=*astring;
    while (*p++){
    printf("%s\n",*p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried the following variations without success.

This code:

```
    char *p=*astring;
    while (*p++){
    printf("%s\n",*p);
    }
```

compiles fine, but upon execution, a segmentation fault error happens and the program immediately exits.

I tried:

```
    while (**p++){
    printf("%s\n",*p);
    }
```

and the program won't compile because of `invalid type argument of 'unary *'`.

I then changed `char *p=*astring;` to `char *p=astring;` and received the warning of `initialization from incompatible pointer type`

I then also tried `char *p=**astring;` and received this compiler warning: `initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast`

I must be confused with the stars or is what I'm trying to do impossible? Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Why isn't `p` considered a "counting variable"?

Comment: How about `char *p=astring;`?  Or `char *p=&(astring[0];`?

Comment: Why do you have casts in `astring[0] = (char*)"ABC"; ...`?

Comment: Unrelated, that your compiler likely spewed warnings or errors at you until you tossed in those `(char*)` casts should be taken to heart; not masked by casting.

Comment: Kninnug, I could remove those casts, but I'd rather be safe than sorry. with those segmentation faults I was getting, I'm lucky I didn't have to restart my computer

Comment: @Mike Fortunately, unless you have a really old system, or are writing system software, application-segfaults rarely crash your whole machine. Secondly, casts usually make code less safe, as they hide information from the compiler. A typecast is saying to the compiler "look, I know it looks like type X, but pretend its type Y". Usually the compiler knows its types better than the programmer.

Comment: Fyi, without the casts and with const-correctness, [see it live](http://ideone.com/UXQFJv)

Comment: `p` needs to be `char **` (since it points into a `char *` array), and the increment should move to the `printf()` so that `printf()` gets the value from before the increment: `char **p=astring; while(*p) printf("%s\n",*p++);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just write

```
for ( char **p = astring; *p; ++p ) puts( *p );
```

Or if your compiler does not support C99 then place the declaration of the pointer after the declaration of the array

```
char *astring[500];
char **p;

//...

for ( p = astring; *p; ++p ) puts( *p );
```

If you have an array with elements of type `T` then the array used in expressions is converted to pointer to its first element. So if there is declaration

```
T array[N];
```

then you can write

```
T *p = array;
```

In your program you have an array of elements of type `char *`. So `T` corresponds to `char *`. And you can write

```
typedef char * T;
T astring[500];
T *p = astring;
```

that is `p` will have type `char **`

Take into account that there is no need to apply casting

```
astring[0]=(char*)"ABC";
astring[1]=(char*)"DEF";
astring[2]=(char*)"GHI";
astring[3]=(char*)NULL;
```

You could write

```
char *astring[500] = { "ABC", "DEF", "GHI"/*, NULL */ };
```

Comment: That for loop gave me `error: 'for' loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode` message

Answer (score 2):

```
char** p = astring;
while (*p != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", *p);
    p++;
}
```

Comment: AlexD, I still receive segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way to do it:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    char *astring[500]={"ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL",NULL};
    char **p=astring;
    while (*p != NULL){
    printf("%s\n",*p);
    *p++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: now question is how to merge that p++ into the while loop without a segfault

Comment: Change  *p++; to p++; or ++p; As for the segmentation fault then the program is correct.